# Drawing 2D bitmap in OpenGL ES (iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, bitmap, 2d

I've been struggling for **hours** trying to render a simple 2D bitmap in OpenGL ES (iOS). While in OpenGL I could simply use glDrawPixels, it doesn't exist in OpenGL ES, neither does glBegin. Seems like glVertexPointer is now deprecated too.

(Note: the bitmap I'm rendering is constantly changing at 60 FPS, so glDrawPixels *is* a better solution than using textures)

I failed to find any documented sample code that draws a bitmap using current APIs.

So to put it shortly: given an array of pixels (in RGBX format, for example), how to I render it, potentially scaled using nearest neighbor, using OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to render a textured quad and implement a model matrix to perform various transforms (e.g. scaling).

#### How to render a textured quad

First you'll need to build a VBO with your quad's vertex positions:

```
float[] positions = {
        +0.5f, +0.5f, +0f,    // top right
        -0.5f, +0.5f, +0f,    // top left
        +0.5f, -0.5f, +0f,    // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, +0f     // bottom left
};

int positionVBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, floatBuffer(positions), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then pass the necessary info to your vertex shader:

```
int positionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Now we'll do the same thing but with the quad's texture coordinates:

```
float[] texcoords = {
        1f, 0f,     // top right
        0f, 0f,     // top left
        1f, 1f,     // bottom right
        0f, 1f      // bottom left
};

int texcoordVBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, floatBuffer(texcoords), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
int textureAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shader.getId(), "texcoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureAttribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(textureAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

You could interleave this data into a single VBO but I'll leave that to the reader. Regardless we've submitted all the quad vertex data to the GPU and told the shader how to access it.

Next we build our texture buffer assuming we have an object called `image`:

```
int texture = glGenTextures();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixels());
```

And pass that info to the shaders:

```
int textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "image");
glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);
```

Check out [open.gl's page on Textures](https://open.gl/textures) for more information.

Finally, the shaders:

*vertex.glsl*

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
varying vec2 uv;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    uv = texcoord;
}
```

*fragment.glsl*

```
varying vec2 uv;
uniform sampler2D image;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture(image, uv);
}
```

Given no other GL state changes this will render the following:

[image: textured quad]

*Note: Since I don't have access to an iOS development environment currently this sample is written in Java. The principle is the same however.*

**EDIT: How to build the shader program**

A shader program is composed from a series of shaders. The bare minimum is a vertex and fragment shader. This is how we would build a shader program from the two shaders above:

```
String vertexSource = loadShaderSource("vertex.glsl");
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexSource);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

String fragmentSource = loadFileAsString("fragment.glsl");
GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentSource);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
```

Once created you would communicate with it via `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glUniform`.

Comment: I'm still unable to get this to work... =/

Compiling the shaders complains about the 'in' and 'out' keywords, and TBH I have no clue what do I do with the shaders anyway (I never used OpenGL ES before, I only have basic "Standard" OpenGL knowledge and I thought rendering a 2D image would be simple enough)

Comment: What version of OpenGL ES and GLSL are you targeting?

Comment: I'd like to support iPhone 4S, so I guess I'm targeting OpenGL ES 2. I have no clue what it implies on the GLSL version. (Again, complete newbie in OpenGL ES, and only basic OpenGL knowledge, sorry!)

Comment: No problem. Different versions have different ways of doing things, thats why I ask :) I've updated the shaders in my answer to be [GLSL ES 1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) specific.

It may be a big leap to go from the fixed-function pipeline (what you're familiar with) to the new world of programmable pipelines but in the long run it will be worth it.

Comment: For OpenGL ES 2.0 (what you'd need for iOS), you'll also have to specify precision qualifiers in the fragment shader and use texture2D, so fragment.glsl above would read something like: `varying highp vec2 uv;
 
 uniform sampler2D image;
 
 void main()
 {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(image, uv);
 }`